# Why is $\frac{\pi}{8}~\left({22.5}^{\circ}\right)$ often selected as a Bell test angle for the CHSH inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality

I understand the mechanism of the [CHSH inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality), however one thing that bugs me is why $b=\frac{\pi}{8}={22.5}^{\circ}$ is selected as a *Bell test angle*:

> Four separate subexperiments are conducted, corresponding to the four terms $E(a,b)$ in the test statistic $S$ (***2***, above). The settings *a*, *a′*, *b* and *b′* are generally in practice chosen to be 0, 45°, 22.5° and 67.5° respectively — the "Bell test angles" — these being the ones for which the QM formula gives the greatest violation of the inequality.
>
> –["CHSH inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality), Wikipedia

It seems like we could select another angle like $\frac{\pi}{100}$, and since $\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{100}\right)} > \cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)},$ it seems like the selection of $\frac{\pi}{100}$ would yield a much better probability, and it doesn't contradict the explanation of setting up states to suit $\frac{\pi}{100}$.

Further, any angle $b \in \left(0, \, \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ would seem to work in place of $b=\frac{\pi}{8},$ though we want to get as close to zero as possible to get the highest probability.

Is this correct? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the probability is limited to $0.851$ (by *Tsirelson's inequality*), due to *no-signaling theorem* and *special relativity*, we cannot take the angle more than $\frac{\pi}{8}$, 
but we can take the angle anywhere between $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{8}$. Since we always want the maximum probability, we choose $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have Tsirelson's inequality limiting the success probability to $\approx 0.85$ which is attained by the states with $\frac{\pi}{8}$. You can take a look at the proof [here](https://mycqstate.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/tsirelsons-bound/).

So basically there has to be something wrong with the way you are constructing your measurements or computing the probabilities. Maybe if you make explicit your derivation of the success probability with $\frac{\pi}{100}$ we can check it.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the way i construct but i totally agree with answer since the probability is limited Tsirelson's inequality due to no signalling theorem and special relativity we cannot take the angle more than $pi/8$

Comment: What do you mean that we cannot take an arbitrary angle? I would say that the angle that the measurement basis make is free for the players to choose and the angle that maximizes their success probability is $\pi/8$.